# Django website loads slow after using requests to check broken links

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, web

My website gives deatails about different servers.
I have used **requests** to check which server ILO IP is not working through http and which is not.

AFter using requests.. the page loads super slow!

My server checks ILO Ips of many servers and if the server is broken it shows the IP as a text and if not it shows a link(THE IP) to the ILO.

Do you know how to make the server load much faster?
Thanks..

models.py -
from django.db import models

import requests

```
class serverlist(models.Model):
    ServerName = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length = 50,blank=True)
    Project = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length = 255,blank=True)
    IP = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)
    ILO = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)
    Rack = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank=True)

    def checkUrlAvailable(self):
        ip_check = 'https://' + self.ILO
        resp = requests.head(ip_check,allow_redirects=False)
        if resp.status_code == 303:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

index.html -

```
{% if server.checkUrlAvailable is True %}

      <a href="//{{ server.ILO }}"> {{ server.ILO }} </a>
            {% else %}
                {{ server.ILO }}


            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

How many servers are in your list exactly? I wouldn't do the available check in python like this. But use javascript, so you can fire up multiple async checks and one status code change a class on the link or something that, or even 'disable' the anchor element. Use JQuery ajax (type HEAD) for this.

Otherwise, I would put some caching on your `checkUrlAvailable` function. But that doesn't change the fact that doing a request takes some time, even a `HEAD`. So on big lists (and thus many requests) it starts to add up.

Comment: Now it's about 100 servers.. it will get maximum to 200 servers in a a few years. Therefore, the cache thing sounds ike a good solution no?

Comment: Caching would be, for example, in ram, or even in redis. So you save the 'status code' of a giving timestamp. And if that is XX minutes or hours ago, you do the request again. But that could make your information stale. Depends how many people look at this page and the number of servers :)

Comment: 200 servers and about 10-15 people looking at the webpage once a day

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Well now it gets fresh information for every pageview for each server. Personally I would use an intermediate (like redis) to store server status + timestamp and use a cronjob or something to update that. Then use the information stored in redis for the template.